# Concerned I may have dropped Malware on my phone via a redirect to an advert?

Tags: internet, malware, antivirus

In short I think I may have a slight chance of having dropped Malware on my phone via an infected ad (redirect was to rdr.harbwire). Am just keen to ascertain the risk given some of the things I have on the phone. I think I am likely OK but would be greatful for a second opinion.

What I was doing;

1. Was surfing a wiki of a TV Show using the standard Android internet browser (on a Samsung). Java Script was on, Cookies were off.
2. Get re-directed to a pop ad over the browsing screen where you could only click OK (address was something like rdr.harbwire). Had seen these on PC's so knew not to click OK. Tried clicking back which didn't work - as I couldn't see how to close the pop up (tried to load in a new screen but re-directed me back to the ad).
3. Quit the browser, used History Eraser & went back in - and it is still there.
4. Found Internet in App.Manager (why did they have to hide it somewhat?) & cleared all data and cache.
5. Went back & it is now gone. Have then switched off all Java Script & Cookies etc.
6. Ran Avast Mobile Security a couple of times (which only seems to scan apps now?) which came back clear.
7. Looked at the internet which seemed to suggest nobody else is panicing (the fact I clicked back bothers me - one of the screens that tried to load in seemed to suggest Malware may have infected or tried to infect my phone).
8. Think I am OK - phone seems OK but I am slightly OCD about these things.

In short is there a way of telling whether I am in the clear or not? I don't do much with the phone but just want to know I am OK. I'm just concerned about the possible risk of a drive-by style download approach from the ad.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like you're in the clear. Remember that OEM web browsers are vulnerable to password sniffing, address spoofing, and XSS sniffing on Android 4.3 Jellybean and below. [More info pt. 1](https://threatpost.com/address-spoofing-bug-haunts-android-stock-browser/112892/) // [More info pt. 2](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/09/16/shocking-android-browser-bug-could-be-a-privacy-disaster-heres-how-to-fix-it/)

Comment: Cheers. Am on 4.4.4 - was aware that everything has risks, so it's why I am about the only one of my friends that actually went with a virus checker above what was installed on the phone. Is there a way of knowing if I am 100% clear? Have asked this elsewhere & have had a similar response. Think I am OK. Was just concerned about the risk of an auto install & run.

Comment: You've kept a clean head in that situation – right steps. I'd say you've been in the clear at step 5 already (I don't think much of those AV apps).

Comment: Cheers. Agreed re: AV apps, but I prefer having something (e.g. I know a bulletproof vest won't stop you being shot in the head etc.).

Comment: Hmm. I don't trust Android AVs, at least not those wo/ an heuristic engine. You avoid responding to the popup, so you managed to not authorizing anything hidden below it. Good job.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman - I agree. Without root, an AV app can't do a thorough scanning job.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I am in the clear, but I'm grateful for all of these opinions. I would upvote them but unfortunately do not have enough points.